# Is it possible to extract the clk frequency to the CPU on ZC702 eval board (Zynq-7000 XC7Z020 SoC)?

Tags: c, embedded, xilinx, zynq-ultrascale+

I am working on a Zynq-7000 XC7Z020 SoC and have implemented an AXI timer and connected it to the PS. Now I want to make it run on a very specific time. and show the countdown in the terminal in seconds. For this I need to know the zynqs clk frequency for my platform. I have used this formula to calculate the seconds: seconds = (2^32- Reset value)/clk frequency

Are there anyway to extract the clk freq in the c code in vitis sdk?
Does anybody have a solution for this, or feedback on this problem?

In advance, thank you for the help.

Comment: The way I do this on any generic embedded system, without studying the details about system clocks and PLL, is to start up a hardware timer and have it toggle a GPIO pin repeatedly. Then measure the square wave you get with a scope.

Comment: Yes that is probably the best solution to get the accurate clk freq. But was just wondering if there where a way to do it on the software side. On solution is to look in Vivado under timing, but this seems a bit inaccurate.